# I was writing the python code for discord and i imported the discord packages. As soon as i run the code its said no attribute name Client in discord

Tags: python, discord, package

import discord
**client = discord.Client()**

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'discord' has no
> attribute 'Client' (most likely due to a circular import)

First of all i write my code like usual. I finished my python code and ran it.
There was an error, it said "they cant find Client in dicord.py" so i uninstall it and ran it again but not working.

Help me sir. I have been writing these for 6 days.
TwT

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<your prefix>')
```

Comment: it said cant find commands in discord.py
sir. i can find the package in my computer disk also.

Comment: did you tried to code? use `from discord.ext import commands`